# Do we need to set move constructor = default? For legacy classes with user declared destructor buildet with C++98/03 in the past?

Tags: c++, c++11

So the question is, lets consider a big legacy project in c++ in the past always build for C++98/03 standard.

And the project followed the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)), so therefore there are a lot of user defined destructors in the project.

If now the project is build for standard C++11/14/17, is it a good idea to set the move constructor = default manually?

Because due to the slide shown by Howard Hinnant at Accu_2014 these classes are not automatically provided with an move constructor.
[image: ACCU2014 Howard Hinnant, Special Members]

So the question is could the project benefit in performance by setting the  move constructor = default for every class?

And to be more precise, lets say after setting the move constructor = default the application runs exactly as before and all unit test work as before.

Do you think there will be a performance benefit by defining the move constructor = default?

Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do you think there will be a performance benefit by defining the move constructor = default?

It's not possible to predict that without studying the code base and running some benchmarks. That being sad, it is likely to positively affect your runtime performance. Having a `= default` move constructor and move assignment operator and given that these do the right thing is never a pessimisation. The worst thing that can happen is that your data member don't benefit from move-construction (e.g. you have a `std::array<int, 1000>` data member), then you end up doing the same copying as before.

> And the project followed the rule of three

This leads to  a consistency issue when you modernize your code. In C++11, the rule of three now is the rule of five. So if you followed the rule of three until now, you should migrate to the rule of five to be consistent, in addition to the runtime performance benefit you might get.

> is it a good idea to set the move constructor `= default` manually?

No. Use `clang-tidy`'s [C.21](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/cppcoreguidelines-special-member-functions.html) check to let a tool scream at you.

Answer (score 2):

If there are user defined destructors, default move constructor and default constructor are probably wrong, that why move was deleted in that case, (copy wasn't historically :( , as you may notice in the table, those cases are red, as ideally, they should be deleted as for move).

so `= default` is probably wrong and you probably need custom one. but if default fits your need, then yes you might add the default one to replace some possible copy by move.

Else you might still write relevant user provided move constructor.